# Import javascript from node_modules in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, node-modules

I installed a npm package which contains a javascript file, what I want to use. The js file name is **all.js** and contains this code:

```
import { initExtended } from './extended'
import Header from './components/header/header'

function initAll(options) {
  // Set the options to an empty object by default if no options are passed.
  options = typeof options !== 'undefined' ? options : {}

  // Allow the user to initialise GOV.UK Frontend in only certain sections of the page
  // Defaults to the entire document if nothing is set.
  var scope = typeof options.scope !== 'undefined' ? options.scope : document
  
  // Find first header module to enhance.
  var $toggleButton = scope.querySelector('[data-module="govuk-header"]')
  new Header($toggleButton).init()

  initExtended(options)
}

export {
  initAll,
  Header
}
```

File **all.js** is located in node_modules.

When I tried to import it directly from index.html like:

```
<script type="module" src="node_modules/@id-sk/frontend/govuk/all.js"></script>
```

It is not working. Console error, file not found.

I also tried import it via angular.json:

```
"scripts": [
   "./node_modules/@id-sk/frontend/govuk/all.js"
]
```

Also not working with error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at scripts.js:15241:1)". The error refers to line:

```
import { initExtended } from './extended'
```

I also tried to import it in polyfills but I don't know how to call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are speaking about `angular.json`, I assume that you are working in an Angular application bootstrapped using the Angular CLI with default settings.

To be able to use this package `@id-sk/frontend` in your typescript files, you have to import it directly into your typescript file.

### 1. Import `@id-sk/frontend` in your TS files

```js
// Import everything into a local variable
import * as govuk from '@id-sk/frontend';
// Import specific object
import { HeaderExtended } from  '@id-sk/frontend';
```

### 2. Run `ng serve`

⚠ *Spoil*: It will lead to *typings errors*

### 3. Let's add or create typings

As `@id-sk/frontend` is not written in typescript, the compile doesn't know about the typings of this library.
Following this statement, you have two choices:

- Find or contribute to [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) in order to create the typings of your package `@id-sk/frontend`
- Create a local file `typings.d.ts` in your `./src` folder to declare an empty module

```
declare module "@id-sk/frontend"
```

### 4. Kill & run `ng serve` again

Enjoy it!

---

### Go further

You can add typings to your module in order to give you autocompletion on the provided objects of `@id-sk/frontend`.

``ts
declare module "@id-sk/frontend" {

```
export interface Options {
    scope?: Document
}

export function initAll(options: Options): void;
```

}